# Custom Y tick text in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset
`structure(list(ValueName = c("Value 11", "Value 14", "Value 13",  "Value 12", "Value 10", "Value 1", "Value 5", "Value 9", "Value 4",  "Value 7", "Value 8", "Value 3", "Value 15", "Value 2", "Value 6",  "Value 11", "Value 14", "Value 13", "Value 12", "Value 10", "Value 1",  "Value 5", "Value 9", "Value 4", "Value 7", "Value 8", "Value 3",  "Value 15", "Value 2", "Value 6", "Value 11", "Value 14", "Value 13",  "Value 12", "Value 10", "Value 1", "Value 5", "Value 9", "Value 4",  "Value 7", "Value 8", "Value 3", "Value 15", "Value 2", "Value 6" ), plotOrder = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L,  12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L,  11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L,  10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), Response = c("A1", "A1", "A1",  "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1",  "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2",  "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3",  "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3"), Percent = c(86.5,  85.3, 84.5, 83.2, 81, 79.5, 77, 76.7, 71, 66.2, 64.5, 60.5, 59.6,  57.2, 53.2, 9.9, 9.4, 10.2, 9.9, 11.8, 14.7, 13.9, 13.5, 15.1,  16.1, 21.3, 21.3, 26.6, 19.8, 18.5, 3.6, 5.3, 5.3, 6.9, 7.2,  5.8, 9, 9.8, 13.9, 17.7, 14.1, 18.2, 13.8, 22.9, 28.2)), .Names = c("ValueName",  "plotOrder", "Response", "Percent"), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))`
which produces the following:

[image]

But I want to change the X and Y tick text according to a custom value.

for example like the following

[image]

Is there any ggplot function to do that? I have looked everywhere but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Take a look at the `labels` argument of `scale_y_discrete` (or `scale_y_continuous` - I can't be sure which one you need as you haven't provided your plotting code).

Comment: @Limey- Yes! You're right about the `scale_y_discrete`. It is working now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try(I filtered and used four `Values`)

```
install.packages("ggh4x")
df %>%
  filter(ValueName %in% c("Value 9", "Value 8", "Value 7", "Value 6")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Percent, ValueName, fill = Response)) +
  geom_col() + scale_y_discrete(labels = c("So On", "Comprehensive", "Clear", "Good")) +
  guides(
    y.sec = ggh4x::guide_axis_manual(
      labels = ~ c("So On", "Incomprehensive", "Unclear", "Bad")
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly the way I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the approach by @Park but using "just" `ggplot2` you could achieve your desired result via a secondary or duplicated axis where I use named vectors of labels. However, this requires to switch to a continuous y scale and to map your `plotOrder` column directly on `y`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

labels <- unique(df$ValueName)
names(labels) <- unique(df$plotOrder)
labels2 <- labels

labels[1:2] <- c("Good", "Clear")
labels2[1:2] <- c("Bad", "Unclear")

ggplot(df, aes(Percent, plotOrder, fill = Response)) +
  geom_col(orientation = "y") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = unique(df$plotOrder), labels = labels, sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = labels2))
```

[image]